# SlickNav menu issue in google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, slicknav

Here is my site: http://www.reliableairinc.com, The slickNav responsive menu icon disappears upon re sizing the browser window  on dynamic pages. Facing this problem only in chrome.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code and or a demo on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get it, try to change the type attribute from `text/x-javascript` to `text/javascript` in the script tag. I think `text/x-javascript` is invalid content type.